# Spatial join of raster data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, spatial-join

How do I perform spatial join of raster data in QGIS? I have raster soil data (tiff), I'd like to join this to an attribute table in excel? I'm not able to view the attribute table either? Is this possible in QGIS, specifically working with raster data?

Comment: Does your Excel data have an x and y?

Comment: No. It has a common field to the values in the raster data

Answer (score 4):

Raster data does not have an attribute table. Shapefiles (vector layers) have attribute tables. If you want to transform a raster file to a shapefile you can use the function "vectorize" in QGIS.

If you are interested in questions like "which value is represented how often" then you need "Zonal Statistics" or do some raster calculations. (both of them you find in the `Raster` menu point of QGIS desktop)
The specific commands you need then depend on the type of raster you have (multi / singleband) and the values you want to obtain.
The search function will direct you to the respective stackexchange questions I presume.

Comment: I'm talking about the attribute table that contains list of cell values and corresponding counts.Its the value field that I need to join to the Excel. This is possible in ArcGIS but I'm looking for a way in QGIS

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly